# Oracle Auto Partition strategy on Integer column

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle12c

I need some help on how to perform auto partition on integer column, similar to how we do on date column like `PARTITION BY RANGE (DIM_DT_ID) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))`.

I have 90 million rows and it sucks in performance and our SLA on query is 2 seconds, i would like to perform partition. What is the best approach and how do i enable auto partition on a Integer column

Our query will always filter by these columns like

```
select * from <tbname> 
where ObjectID =1346785 
and patentnumber=23456.
```

Comment: I am sure you don't have 90 million **tables** - you probably mean a single table, with that many **rows**. Your lack of attention to detail (on a question you post here, asking for help) is not a good sign. Then: You want to partition on MORE THAN one column? You show TWO columns at the end of your question. What are the ranges of values for those two columns? (Typical values, as you illustrated, are helpful, but you need to provide more information for a meaningful answer.)

Comment: sorry made necessary changes..ObjectID range is 1 to 4010 and patentnumber is kind of a surrogate key

Comment: OK, then partitioning by ObjectID shouldn't be an issue, but partitioning by patentnumber may be. How are patentnumber values generated? Also note that if ObjectID range is 1 to 4010, it doesn't make sense in your post to demonstrate filtering by `ObjectID=1346785`.

Comment: Mathguy..i'm just making an example here, as i cant paste the original query for legality sake..

Comment: @sunnybabau That query looks like it would benefit more from a multi-column index than a partition.  Partitions generally work best for operations that have to return or process a large amount of data, and indexes work best for operations that return or process a small amount of data.  The large range of ObjectID, combined with patentnumber being "kind of a surrogate key" implies the query will only return a small number of rows.

Answer (score 4):

> "i'm just making an example here, as i cant paste the original query for legality sake"

Fair enough, but the advice we give you will only be as good as the information you give us. So far, nothing you have posted suggests you need Partitioning.

The pasted query would perform well with a compound index, and would probably benefit from compression of the leading column:

```
 create index your_table_lookup_index 
      on your_table(ObjectID, patentnumber) compress 1;
```

If that's a unique combination then make the index unique.

> how do i enable auto partition on a Integer column

However, if you think you do have a genuine use case for Partitioning then we can use Interval Partitioning with integers as well as dates. This statement will create a table partitioned on `objectid` with a partition for every ten values.

```
create table your_table (
      objectid   number,
      patentnumber        number,
      created_date date
)
partition by range (objectid)
interval (10)
(
   partition p_00010 values less than (10)
);
```

On your posted figures that would be about 400 partitions with around 225000 rows per partition. Is that a good choice? Who can tell? You know your data and your use cases, we don't: perhaps a partition per `objectid` (i.e. with `interval (1)`) would be better.

You already have a table so you need to split it into Partitions. The standard of way of doing this would be

1. create a new table with your partitioning strategy (like above) but with the default partition ranged for `values less than (MAXVALUE)`
2. use partition exchange to move the existing table data into the new
   structure
3. drop the old table and rename the table to the old table; resolve
   foreign keys and other dependencies.
4. iteratively split the partition into the required range

This is a fairly time-consuming process. You have tagged your question `[oracle12c]`; if you're using Oracle 12c R2 you should definitely look at its online conversion mechanism, which is a single command. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/online-conversion-of-a-non-partitioned-table-to-a-partitioned-table-12cr2).

Remember that Partitioning for performance is a tricky game. While it can improve queries which return a large number of rows aligned with the Partition key it can make no difference to other queries, or even impair their performance. In particular, any query which does not include the partition key (`objectid` in your case) will likely perform worse after partitioning the table .

---

Final aside: as you know but for the benefit of future Seekers, Partitioning is a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition license. We're not allowed to use it unless we've paid for it.

Comment: Good point about the online conversion, will definitely look into that.

Comment: Great points.. `partition by range (objectid) interval (10)`  - never seen or had a use case which required to do that so far :-)